# Ubuntu internal mic doesn't work

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04, microphone

have new laptop and found problem with built-in mic, which did not work with 18.04 before the upgrade.
**

- laptop: [acer swift 3 sf315-52](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/search?q=swift%203%20sf315-52)
- ubuntu: was 18.04, now upgraded to 19.04

**

```
uname -a
Linux swift 5.0.0-37-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 00:14:01 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What were done:

- upgraded OS
- added and changed lines to the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
- as was suggested tried to remap pins with hdajackretask to 12 and 13
- tried to change settings in alsamixer
- pavucontrol - tried to set one channel to zero, tried to change config to audioduplex

[alsmixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2YZq.png)
[pavucontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqWYH.png)

---

i bought my laptop in Ukraine though my was with Linux like system, seems to me linpus, so I've installed Linux instead. By the way, i guess, it will work on window( i saw a lot of issues with hda intel pch, realtec alc256 and Ubuntu over internet, so i guess that is the problem  ( unfortunately nothing didn't help me from those recommendations

Comment: unfortunately no, it was reason for upgrade, i hoped that upgrade can fix the issue :( i am not experiences linux user, so tried any possible solution )

Comment: All four models found at Acer of the SF315-52 (SF315-52-51NV, SF315-52-52YN, SF315-52-88A4, and SF315-52G-55M) were sold with Win10 Home. Did the mic work with Win10 Home? Please click [edit] and put your response in the question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].